# Running a script as administrator without login as administrator

Tags: permissions, powershell, file-permissions

An old mate of mine used to say "Any question is stupid. Stupid is avoid asking"

I'm pretty new on Windows System Administrator (just 3/4 months) and recently i started working on powershell 2.0.

I'm administering a set of windows services, one of them is going to try to execute a "Start-Service" command as part of a powershell script. This windows service is running under a domain account "ATG\Boot" as part of administrators group.

But, Start-Service/Stop-Service always fails for this reason:

> Stop-Service : Service 'SQL Server
>   Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)
>   (ReportServer)' cannot be stopped due
>   to the follow ing error: Cannot open
>   ReportServer service on computer '.'.
>   At line:1 char:13
>   + Stop-Service <<<<  *Report*
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError:
>   (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController)
>   [Stop-Service],
>   ServiceCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand

This error is reproduced when i execute script from shell, but works properly when i run script with "Run as administrator" option.

I would like to empathize that user is part of local administrators group.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the UAC enabled?  You probably have to have you script elevate itself.  This probably means that your script will display a UAC prompt.

This was the first search hit for 'powershell uac prompt'.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566969/showing-the-uac-prompt-in-powershell-if-the-action-requires-elevation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I use to stop SQL Server service. By using start-process with the -runas switch a separate PowerShell process will be started as admin. You will be prompted for UAC.

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -argumentlist '-noprofile -command get-service -Name "MSSQL`$R2" | ? {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Stop-Service -Force' -verb runas
```

I have blog post here about this subject.